# Enter different ConversationHandler based on user arguments

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a command im my telegram bot: `/collection`. This function receives one of two arguments from the user: a or l, e.g `/collection f`.

`/collection` calls a `collection_handler` function, there the arguments are handled and depending on it the right function is called:

```py
async def collection_handler(update, context):
    collection = " ".join(context.args).lower()
    if collection == 'a':
        await show_collection_album(update, context)
    elif collection == 'l':
        await show_collection_list(update, context)
    else:
         # invalid argument handle
         .....
```

I want to convert this function to a ConversationHandler, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried:

```py
async def collection_handler(update, context):
    collection = " ".join(context.args).lower()
    if collection == 'a':
       return ALBUM
    
    ......
ALBUM, LIST = range(2)
coll_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('collection', collection_handler)],
    states={
        ALBUM: [CallbackQueryHandler(show_collection_album)],
        LIST: [CallbackQueryHandler(show_collection_list)],
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, conv_end)],
    block=False,

)
```

This locks the Conversation in the collection_handler, since there is no callback from the user in this first part.

Also, the functions show_collection_album and show_collection_list works in this way:

```py
async def show_collection_album(update, context)
    # this will show the photos the user has, one by one.
    # A inline keyboard markup is defined, with two arrows <-(index-1) ->(index+1)  
    # the user cycles through the photos when clicking in an arrow
    # when the user clicks one arrow, the function has a callbackqueryhandler that
    # updates the index and calls show_collection_album again, showing the right photo.
    index = context.user_data["album_index"]
    photos = context.user_data["photos"]
    media = open(photos[index], 'rb')
    await context.bot.send_photo(user_id, media,
                                               caption=caption,
                                               reply_markup=album_reply_markup, 
                                               parse_mode='Markdown')
async def album_index_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    index = int(query.data.replace('a', '')) + int(context.user_data.get("album_index"))
    context.user_data["album_index"] = index

    await collection_album(update, context)
```

In a conversation handler, instead of having the functions calling each other, I would do:
`return None` so the function calls itself again.

It would be simpler if I could create a ConversationHandler for each state, e.g the
`show_collection_album` would be the entry point and the index handler would be a state.

This can be easily solved by adding two different commands to Telegram: `/collectionalbum` and `/collectionlist`, but I don't like this approach. I want to keep the arguments.